# Are invisible creatures harder to pinpoint via hearing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, skills, invisibility

Invisibility spell states that its subject gains +20 to stealth. This makes it really hard to pinpoint a creature by something other than sight (i.e. hearing).

But what if invisible creature says something?
Does fixed DC of a conversation gets modified by creature's bonus to stealth checks, bringing pinpointing DC from a reasonable 20 (0 base DC to hear conversation +20 pinpointing) to a whooping 40 (0 base DC to hear conversation +20 pinpointing +20 invisibility)? Or does it remain fixed and 20?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A creature can generally notice the presence of an active invisible
>   creature within 30 feet with a DC 20 Perception check. The observer
>   gains a hunch that "something's there" but can't see it or target it
>   accurately with an attack. It's practically impossible (+20 DC) to
>   pinpoint an invisible creature's location with a Perception check.
>   Even once a character has pinpointed the square that contains an
>   invisible creature, the creature still benefits from total concealment
>   (50% miss chance). There are a number of modifiers that can be applied
>   to this DC if the invisible creature is moving or engaged in a noisy
>   activity.
>
> In combat or speaking –20

So that makes total DC 20 Base -20 speaking +20 pinpoint = 20 DC
Much more simple:
http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html

Comment: @MikeQ I should note that your answer was helpful to.

Comment: Might also note that creatures with blind sight might not suffer the pinpoint penalty depending on the type of blind sight and the type of invisibility. For example an ethereal creature wouldn't make movement sounds thus still invisible to hearing based blind sight and echolocation unless speaking, but a human under an invisibility spell likely would be locatable.

Comment: @MikeQ While you are always a final arbiter for your own answers, take a glance on [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/another-poster-has-answered-correctly-should-i-delete-my-answer) and [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/when-a-better-answer-is-supplied-after-my-answer-was-accepted-what-should-i-do) meta posts. In any case have fun and thanks for participation!